# How to add "more" at the end of UILabel text after truncating in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uilabel

In my application I am showing a text on two lines in a Tableview cell.
But I have an issue at the end of second line: The text is truncating and showing ...

My requirement is to show a More button after two dots.
The number of dots should depend on more button width.

How can I add this dynamically?
Please help me.

Comment: try to divide your problem into smaller ones. e.g. add a button, expand/collapse cell when button is pressed

Comment: Fixed some grammar and formatting

Answer (score 1):

The UILabel don't have feature like this. You have to create a custom label (subclass) of UILabel of your own to achieve this.

Comment: Nitheesh thanks for your reply. Is there any way to add few characters after truncate label text to ....

Comment: No way, because the truncation is managed by UI label. This is the default functionality and to customize this you have to subclass the UILabel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel). It has a very useful property called `attributedTruncationToken` for adding at the end of label text. It can also manage links.